# Jquery throw only one action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have organized the page this way:

```
<div class="singlePost">
        <div class="post">  </div>
        <div class="comments" data-idPost="310"> </div>
        <div class="formComment">
            <textarea data-idPost="310"></textarea>
            <button data-idPost="310">Insert</button>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="singlePost">
        <div class="post">  </div>
        <div class="comments" data-idPost="304"> </div>
        <div class="formComment">
            <textarea data-idPost="304"></textarea>
            <button data-idPost="304">Insert</button>
        </div>
 </div>
```

I used html5 data-attributes to distinguish posts and my jquery code is:

```
$(".formCommento button").click(function() {

    idPost=$(this).attr('data-idpost');
    text=$('textarea[data-idpost="'+idPost+'"]').val();
    noty({text: 'I\'m going to insert '+text});
    //and here i make the ajax request
    return false;

});
```

I think this is not the way to organize this kind of stuff. I have the problem that when i click on the button i have multiple actions running together so the same comment is inserted several times. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: You don't really need the `data-idPost` to tie the related elements together. When the button is clicked you can use `$(this).prev().val()` (or `$(this).closest("div.formComment").find("textarea").val()` if you want to be more flexible) to get the value of the related textarea. I don't see anything in your code that would cause "multiple actions running together". (I assume the "o" on the end of `formCommento` in your JS is just a typo in the question?)

Comment: I need the data-idPost to save the post's Id and then send it to php code

Comment: My point is that you don't need to repeat the `data-idPost` on every related element to tie them together. Put it on _one_ of the elements, just the button or just the div, and use DOM traversal methods (as per my previous comment) to figure out which elements belong together - that would make both the html and the JS neater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are learning to "organize" as well, I would suggest only to use once your `data-`, like:

```
<div class="singlePost" data-postId="310">
    <div class="post">  </div>
    <div class="comments"> </div>
    <div class="formComment">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button class="btn-submit">Insert</button>
    </div>
 </div>
<div class="singlePost" data-postId="311">
    <div class="post">  </div>
    <div class="comments"> </div>
    <div class="formComment">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button class="btn-submit">Insert</button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

then, fire it for every button:

```
$(".singlePost .btn-submit").click(function() {
    var singlePost = $(this).closest(".singlePost"), // get singlePost block
        postId = singlePost.attr("data-postId"),  // read data attribute
        txt = singlePost.find("textarea").val(); // get it's own textarea value

    // do your magic
});
```

Here's a live example: http://jsbin.com/iyomaj/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

try this, pass related [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context), by default jQuery uses document as context so it search in whole document

```
$(".formComment button").click(function() {
    var parentdiv = $(this).closest('.formComment');
    idPost=$(this).attr('data-idpost');
    text=$('textarea[data-idpost="'+idPost+'"]',parentdiv ).val();
    noty({text: 'I\'m going to insert '+text});
    //and here i make the ajax request
    return false;

});
```

Comment: But isn't the `data-idPost` value different for each textarea? You don't need a context when the values are different. Why do you still try to select the textarea by that attribute when you can just say `$(this).closest("div.formComment").find("textarea").val()`?